# jQuery boxer close icon click event not working on windows phone

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-8, lightbox

Im using [Boxer Lightbox](http://formstone.it/components/boxer) for a popup form im using, when testing on any other device other than a windows phone the popup works fine. In Winodows phone, the popup shows, animates and renders correctly. but for some odd reason the popup does not close when the user clicks the x button. i have tested this on many windows phones and they all dont close the popup. everything works fine on any other device including desktop. I suspect the JQuery click is not firing, or the particular `span` tag they used is not being recognized by windows.

Comment: This should be logged as an issue on the project's github repo: https://github.com/benplum/Boxer/issues - if you have some code you've used to try and fix or debug the problem then please post it so it's easier for people to help.

Comment: https://github.com/benplum/Boxer/issues/22 fixed @joe